# Removing all non-alphabet characters from a list

Tags: python

I am building a very simple translator program that uses wordreference.com to look up the meanings of words.

I am not very good at Python (3.4) but I was able to make this
(Also, I know the n = n + 1 thing I have isn't currently working, I did this on purpose to test other things!)

```
import webbrowser
import sys
trans = True
print('What language will you be translating FROM?')
lang = input()
n = 1
print('Ok, ' + lang + ', what word would you like to translate from ' + (lang) + ' to English?')
while trans == True:
    if n > 99:
        print('Another one: ')
    word = input()
    word = (word.lower())
    list = word.split()
    if lang == 'French':
        lang = 'fren'
    if lang == 'french':
        lang = 'fren'
    for word in list:    
        webbrowser.open('http://www.wordreference.com/' + (lang) + '/' + (str(word)))
        n = n + 1
```

My question is, how would I remove things such as commas, and exclamation points from the list, but NOT apostraphes 
My test sentence is 'Je vais bien, merci!', I want it to open the amount of tabs as the words, (which it does), but instead of it being

```
Je vais bien, merci!
```

I want it to be
    Je vais bien merci

I know how to use

```
word.isalpha()
```

But this only makes it so I cannot use the program at all if the words are not alphabetical.
Thanks in adavance!

Comment: Add ch != "'" to your check.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will remove non-alphabet characters excepting apostrophes and spaces.

```
>>> s = "Je vais bien, merci!"
>>> "".join(c for c in s if c.isalpha() or c in " '")
'Je vais bien merci'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ahuh, I tried to implement this but could not as this just prints it immediately.

Comment: I tried 'word = (the code you suggested). But if it contained more then one word or any of that, it did nothing, literally nothing

Comment: Nevermind! I got it to work. Thankyou so much you were a huge help!